# DC current limiting in FOC for PMSM

Tags: motor-controller, pmsm, vector-control

I have implemented field oriented control for pmsm motor .

FOC algorithm takes care of phase current limiting.

Can anyone guide me how can we do battery current limiting in foc ?

Comment: Do you know how to to current limiting on any circuit involving a battery?

Comment: Not really. I am more into programming stuff. But hardware engineers in my team have used a op- amp circuit to sense battery current and I am reading it via ADC channel. But I am confused how can I include it in main FOC blocks.

Comment: You need current sensing to control torque., voltage sensing to control speed, phase control to make it synchronous in optimum phase rotor position

Comment: Did you find the solution for this @pujit?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily the battery current would not be limited except to disconnect or shut down to protect the battery. You could monitor the battery current and send a command to the FOC to reduce the limit setting if the battery current reaches a certain level. That would be somewhat problematic however because the battery current directly represents power and the motor current represents torque. At low motor speed, you can have maximum motor current with low battery current.